# Установка OpenJDK на Windows

Tags: windows, openjdk, java

Добрый день. На первом же занятии по основам программирования на java для чайников дали задание установить `OpenJDK`. У меня `Windows`. Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно не просто скачать дистрибутив, но и совершить кучу доп. операций, чтобы все работало?

jdk7 установлен, работает.

Инструкцию пыталась читать, но для новичка сложно.

Может быть, у кого-нибудь есть мануал для тех, кто в танке? Спасибо.

Comment: А можно нескромный вопрос: нафига OpenJDK? Особенно под Windows. Особенно если уже установлен официальный JDK. Я понимаю, некоторые линуксоиды стремятся пользоваться только свободным ПО, но вы же к ним явно не относитесь.

Comment: Вы еще мягко задали вопрос. Я второй день порываюсь задать его преподавателю. Дополнительное домашнее задание. Для чайника. Угу.

Comment: Пожалуй, самое доступное, что мне удалось найти: http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.ru/2012/09/building-openjdk-on-windows.html Внимательно прочитайте эту простыню, пошлите нафиг вашего преподавателя и пользуйтесь стандартным JDK.

Comment: оу! спасибо! буду читать.

Comment: Вообще-то православные Java разработчики не используют OpenJDK. OpenJDK это отрыжка линуксоидов, но отношения к реальной жизни увы имеет мало.

Comment: @Barmaley, мягко говоря вы совсем не правы. Oracle JDK7 как раз основан на OpenJDK7 и у них практически идентичный код. https://weblogs.java.net/blog/robogeek/archive/2009/01/it_will_be_open.html

Comment: @misha-nesterenko вы мягко говоря, неправильно читаете:

Я написал *православные разработчики*, имея ввиду, что вопрос скорее находится в области религии (веры) нежели, в реальной плоскости. Я вот не верю в OpenJDK, равно как и в IcedTea JDK и проч. клоны, вы верите в OpenJDK - ну и слава Будде.

Примеры:
а) Попробуйте, скажем собрать Android не под Sun/Oracle JDK - увидите что будет. В Гугле очевидно, православные разработчики

б) Запустите Intellij IDEA под OpenJDK - ваш словарный запас обогатится нецензурным матом. В JetBrains тоже работают православные разработчики

Ну и.т.д.

Comment: @misha-nesterenko да, и кстати, вы хотя бы прочтите сами внимательно статью на которую вы ссылаетесь. С чего вы взяли этот бред, что дескать Oracle JDK основан на OpenJDK? То что у них 99% кода совпадает еще не означает, что Oracle JDK основан на OpenJDK...

Comment: @Barmaley,`Okay, given that there is not a Java7 JSR and all the JCP stuff related to that issue ... Hopefully all that will be straightened out and we do have a proper Java7 JSR, so for the following please assume that's the case, that Java7's JSR status is straightened out ... the plan is that beginning with OpenJDK7/JDK7 that the code bases will be nearly identical. It is obviously expensive to maintain a fork, and if JDK7 were to diverge strongly from OpenJDK7 it would do two things: a) be very expensive, b) undermine our efforts at an open source ecosystem. `

Comment: @Barmaley, это вы несете чушь (причем уже не в первый раз). `То что у них 99% кода совпадает еще не означает, что Oracle JDK основан на OpenJDK...`, конечно, это просто случайность. Вы как Фома неверующий, говоришь ему очевидные вещи а он неверит. Поищите хоть немного в интернете как организован процесс разработки jdk7 и какую роль там играет openjdk7.

Comment: @misha-nesterenko вот это дась... О как! человек который не отличает `join()` от асинхронности и не понимает историю создания OpenJDK будет учить папу жить. Я вообще умолкаю... На правах модера я вообще могу забанить вас за такую ересь, да уж не буду - живите. С такими жить даже интереснее :)

P.S.

>The OpenJDK 7u project, which is **based on** JDK 7 and produces 
>updates to the existing Java 7 releases.

Comment: @Barmaley, вот вы и написали что код из openjdk попадает в oracle jdk. А изначально код был в oracle/sun jdk потом его опубликовали в openjdk. openjdk это `reference implementation` джава машины, так как это вяжется с тем что openjdk не имеет отношения к реальной жизни? А по поводу join, кто то закрыл комментарии к вопрос (уж не вы ли постарались на правах модера?), а то я бы я там ответил.

Comment: @misha-nesterenko не там ищете... комментарии к `join` я не закрывал, просто количество комментариев ограничено системой :) OpenJDK если даже и является референсной реализацией - увы к реальным девелоперам отношения пока имеет мало - примеры я уже приводил.

Answer (score 3):

Установить вобщем то не проблема. Я только не знаю есть ли где то бинарники для `windows`. Для линукса такие существуют.

Для `windows` можно собрать из исходного кода [OpenJDK Build README](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html)

Ну и если надо только бинарники, то вот:

- x86: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14767221/j2sdk-image-x86.7z
- x64: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14767221/j2sdk-image-x64.7z

Answer (score -1):

Вот в этом [репозитории на гитхабе](https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds) есть готовые бинарники, спасибо alexkasko. В релизах там только 6я версия - но на [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds/) есть более свежие релизы.

Там же есть описание, как билдить OpenJDK самому.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы всегда можете оставлять комментарии под **своими** вопросами и ответами. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/57917)

Comment: Там 14й год последний. Впрочем, помочь эта ссылка автору и правда может.

Comment: PS @Saidolim это именно что ответ на вопрос. Да, его надо капитально редактировать, исправляя стиль - но это все-таки ответ.